# Write polynomials as irreducible polynomials

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Write $x^4+x^3+3x^2+x+2$ as a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb Z_5[x]$.

I only know that the factor can be factored as $(x^2+1)(x^2+x+2)$ but I don't quite understand the concept of a polynomial is reducible modulo every prime . Can someone help me?

Comment: $x^2+1=(x+2)(x+3)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: And in a field it is the same to be a irreducible polynomial of degree 2 to not have any root in the field.